# How can i validate url in Yii

Tags: yii

I have a form in Yii.

It have model Validation.

In that form I have to  insert url in textfield.

```
eg:https://www.google.co.in
```

In database I kept fields as varchar.

Rules in model are

```
public function rules() {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('url', 'required'),
        array('name, url', 'length', 'max' => 255),

        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('name, url', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
    );
}
```

How can I keep validation for this in Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try This:-

return array(
    array('yoururl', 'required'),
    array('yoururl', 'url'),//for url validation
    // The following rule is used by search().
    // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
    array('name, yoururl', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array('inputURL', 'url')
```

and if you want to add http in front if missing use

```
array('website', 'url',defaultScheme' => 'http')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use url validator

this way `array('siteurl', 'url'),`

```
public function rules() {
// NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
// will receive user inputs.
return array(
    array('url', 'required'),
    array('name, url', 'length', 'max' => 255),
    array('url', 'url'),
    // The following rule is used by search().
    // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
    array('name, url', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
);
```

}